# mysql update x rows with the same date then move to next date

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm looking to perform an update in SQL that will update a specific number of rows with a date then move on to the next group and date.

For example, let's say I have 4000 rows in a `subscriptions` table. I need to populate the first 100 rows with today's date in the `suspended_on` field, then the next 100 rows with tomorrow, the next 100 with the day after, until there are no more rows in the `suspended_on` field.

not sure where to begin, sorry...

Comment: or at least provide with related table structure and sample input,output. Thanks

Comment: I'll suggest using row_number with paramaters so each row has kind of rank, then add a lookup table for the update contain two columns, ID_RANGE (1 for 1-99 , 2 for 100-199 ...) and UpdatedDate with the date need to be updated. And then join between them and update.

Comment: Can you clarify which RDBMS

Answer (score 1):

for first 1000 rows

```
UPDATE subscriptions a 
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT ID,@row := @row+1 row_num 
  FROM subscriptions, (SELECT @row :=0 ) vars order by ID
) b on a.ID = b.ID set a.suspended_on = '02/22/2014'
WHERE @row <= 1000
ORDER BY ID
```

next 1000 records

```
UPDATE subscriptions a 
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT ID,@row := @row+1 row_num 
  FROM subscriptions, (SELECT @row :=0 ) vars order by ID
) b on a.ID = b.ID set a.suspended_on = '02/23/2014'
WHERE @row BETWEEN 1000 AND 2000
ORDER BY ID
```